# Crystal Report for Visual studio 2017 crashes out on "setdatasource" property of the report

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I just installed visual studio 2017 and Crystal Report sp22. I noticed that all my old reports which I created in visual studio 2015 have stopped working.

I tried to step over the code and noticed that at the line where the `DataSource` is set (setdatasource) the project will crash.

Can someone advice me on what to do?

Comment: Post some code and try to better illustrate the problem, so that a user can get to a solution faster.

Comment: Does it give you an error message when it crashes?

Comment: SqlDbDataAdapter2.Fill(DSTblAdmission, "Table")               crReportTblNewAdmissionForm.SetDataSource(DSTblNewAdmissionFormMain1)

     GeneralReportViewer.ReportSource = crReportTblNewAdmissionForm

  The program runs smoothly until it gets to setdatasource

Comment: There is no error message. windows just pop up "Application has stopped working"

Answer (score 0):

Has finally fixed it after 2 weeks of error.
I enabled the common language runtime and GPU memory access exception, on exception settings
From there i noticed that the crystal report file "crdb_adoplus" was not upgraded to the current version. I copied the most current from "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86" and replaced the one i have in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Beside update of the configuration file by adding `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>` you must also remove all of the old dll files from the application folder before upgrade to new ones.